# Pull out matches with formula

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to compare two columns and pull out the data is the same? I have tried multiple formulas but unable to produce multiple data? I am using 2016 Excel for Mac.

Sample info:

[image]

I have tried this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$15000,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$15=$B$1:$B$15,ROW($A$1:$A$15)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$1‌5,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$15000=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$15)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

Comment: Can you show something you've tried?

Comment: =IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$15000, SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$15=$B$1:$B$15,ROW($A$1:$A$15)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$15,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$15000=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$15)),ROW(1:1)),2))

Comment: What I would really like is compare columns in different sheets just thought if I could get this formula I would make it work?

Comment: Please edit your question with this, it's important information 

Comment: Can you rewrite your question? It's not clear what you want. Your screen shot is not helpful since it only has names. What do you want the third column to say? Fill it out as if the formula worked

Answer (score 1):

To compare the 2 columns you can use this formula:
**=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$21,0)),"No Match","Match")**

$B$2:$B$21 is the second column and 0 to have exact match, A2 is the first name in column A and you can drag it down.
It will give you Match if the Name is in Column A and Column B and No Match if not butif you want in the same column try sort ascending before writing any formula.

Comment: This came back no match and there are matches?

Comment: show with a screen shot to explain what happened

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula to check if two cells match or not.

`=IF(A4=E4,"Match","NoMatch")`

[image]

Comment: Sorry I got it to work but I want it to say John James, Sue Stone not match, no match?